# How do I connect the chime unit with my doorbell camera?

Tags: low-voltage, doorbell

I bought an Amcrest AD110 doorbell camera. I installed and it works but I noticed pressing the button does not ring the doorbell. I can't figure out how I am meant to wire this.

Here's the transformer:
[image]

The wires on the right run to a second chime unit which no longer exists. They have been disconnected for years and the old doorbell worked fine this way.

Here's the chime:
[image]

Ignore that the wires are not properly attached. They are loose and uncapped because I was just messing with it. With the wires connected this way (the two whites tied together), the doorbell camera gets power but the chime unit does not activate when the button is pressed.

The "chime kit" shown in the diagram below was connected to the reds.

Here's the wiring diagram from the manual (page 7 if you would like to look it up yourself):
[image]

I have a crappy (Harbor Freight) but functional multimeter and a non-contact voltage tester but not much else to work with right now. I'm not willing to go to big orange to buy anything due to the current global issue that shall not be named.

- Between the terminals of the transformer I get ~23 VAC.
- Between the right-most red and the bundle of whites I get ~23 VAC.
- Between the left most red and the bundle of whites I get ~23 VAC.
- Between the reds I get ignorable voltage (random and under 1 VAC).

  1. What is this chime kit that I am supposed to connect to the chime? Do I really need it?
  2. Does my chime have two pairs of wires because of the other chime unit that no longer exists? If yes, how can I determine which wires I no longer need in this chime?
  3. How do I need to connect this together?

Comment: the wiring diagram of the chime is embedded in the plastic of the chime ... briefly connect the two wires from the transformer directly to the chime ... try the middle and right screw terminal ... then try the middle and left screw terminal .... you will hear the difference

Comment: @jsotola There are two pairs of wires in the chime, how do I tell which ones are from the transformer when both reds give the same voltage against the whites? I understand about front/rear chimes sounding different. Not clear how that applies to this situation.

Comment: think about this .... you have a light bulb ... one pair of wires goes to a switch .... the other pair of wires goes to a battery .... how can you use the lightbulb to determine which wire pair goes to the battery?

Comment: I figured out which wires are to the trans but now what? Yes if I touch them to the terminals of the chime it dings. So then why does it not ding when the button is pressed when connected the exact same way which works with a regular doorbell rather than the camera?

Comment: Opens browser. Searches for installation instructions. Takes picture of instructions on phone. Posts question from phone with embedded image. Ignores the fact that the post could have been made from the desktop machine and the link to the instructions included so others would have had a nice, clear view of them, and browsed the rest if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The chime kit keeps a resistor inline to power the lines when the button isn't pressed, to power the doorbell, camera, wifi, etc.

Normally there should be no current flowing the doorbell, unless the button is pressed and the lines are shorted.

When the button is pressed, the lines are directly shorted, and the bell should ring.
I have a similar setup, I had to go in the app and 'enable chime', I think it enables a circuit in the doorbell to short the lines when the button is pressed, not exactly sure.